# OpenID Python direct login script

Tags: python, django, authentication, openid

I am using Python/Django-nonrel. I wish to created a website which can verify/login a user with a pair of OpenID url/password using a script (python code), not manually login. Is this doable? Thanks.

Comment: The OpenID identity URL is not a username. There is no URL/password authentication.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to allow a script (a http request, not a human user) to come to my site with his openid/password and, if verified, get the files this user stored in the site. Is there anyway I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to authenticate using OpenID from a script, although it's a little bit trickier than you might think if you're not used to the OpenID workflow.

Just remembed that OpenID is a three-party authentication mechanism.  The three parties involved are:

1. the OpenID End User: your Python script
2. the OpenID Consumer: the web server that serves resources
3. the OpenID Identity Provider: where you authenticate (e.g. MyOpenID, Yahoo, etc.)

**Important:** The whole purpose of the OpenID workflow is that you *never, ever* exchange a password with the web server that provides the resource (#2)!  You must login to *another website* (e.g. MyOpenID) in order to prove your identity.

Thus, the key to implementing the OpenID workflow as part of a script is to use a web automation tool that mangages cookies and follows redirects.  Mechanize for Python][1](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) is a high-level tool that conveniently implements most of this typical User Agen (browser) logic.

---

Keep in mind that once the web server (#2) redirects the User Agent (#1) to the Identity Provider's (#3) website, there will be some Identity Provider scripting involved.  This provider-specific scripting is usually where you will input the username/password combination to prove that you own the identity URL.

Once this is done, the identity provider (#3) will redirect your User Agent back to the web server (#2), at which point the web server will serve the resource (or redirect you to the URL which serves the requested resource).

So, assuming you have a high-level object that implements most of the typical User Agent logic (e.g. redirects and cookies), the rest should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Hi Andre, Thank you very much for your help. I will try Mechanize. Is it possible to find a similar example? If not, I will try to figure out the whole thing gradually.